# Exact reference for Liouville theorem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

It seems hard for me to find that the solution of the following equation
$$
\Delta u+e^u=0
$$
defined on a simply-connected domain $D\subset R^2$ must be of form
$$
u(z)=\log\frac{4|f'|^2}{(1+|f|^2)^2},
$$
for some holomorphic function $f$ on $D$. A lot of authors claim that it is classical, but in my memeory the Liouville theorem claims that a bounded holomorphic function on $R^2$ must be a constant. It seems there is a gap between them, so could any one help me to move on?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that, nowadays, this theorem follows immediately from basic differential geometry: The point is that, when $u:D\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the above equation, the conformal metric $g = e^{u(z)}|\mathrm{d}z|^2$ on $D$ has Gauss curvature $K\equiv +1$, so we must have $g = f^*(g_0)$, where $f:D\to\mathbb{CP}^1=S^2=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is *meromorphic* and $g_0 = 4|\mathrm{d}w|^2/(1+|w|^2)^2$ is the standard metric with $K\equiv+1$. Of course, $f$ is only unique up to unitary linear fractional transformations; it cannot always be taken to be *holomorphic*, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that the Liouville theorem you are thinking of is the [**boundedness theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), whereas the result you have in mind is from a different paper of Liouville's? In particular, the paper:

> Liouville, J. (1853). Sur l’équation aux différences partielles ${d^2 \log \lambda \over du dv}\pm {\lambda \over 2a^2}= 0$. *Journal de mathématiques pures et appliquées*, 71-72.

You can find [**the latter paper**](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1853_1_18_A3_0.pdf) cited by quite a number of [**more recent ones**](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=7020573911262658874&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en) including, for example, [**a paper**](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-003-0481-1) of Brito and Leite with a result as you specified. See, e.g., (4) on pp. 501-502:

---

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, especially the uniquness upto fractional linear transformation is also proved in your cited paper, thanks a lot!